# How to restrict dropdown in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
class A(models.Model):
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(B, unique=True)
```

I have the code above - how can I ensure that in the dropdown under A's Admin, for 'foreign', I am only presented with unique choices? This is just to prevent a user violating the uniqueness constraint and being presenting with the admin error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey() [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey). The downside is having to resort to [raw SQL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#transactions-and-raw-sql).

```
class AModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "foreign":
        kwargs["queryset"] = B.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_a where not exists (select id from myapp_b where b.id=a.foreign_id')
    return super(AModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

IMHO "non-null non-blank unique FKs" looks like good opportunity to rethink your modeling - may be merging two models. Everytime I found myself struggling too hard in Django I was trying to do something naive.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, as the admin template is not rendered correctly - I get:
"Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'"

Comment: If you open a bug at http://code.djangoproject.com/ I can send a patch to add a dummy all() method to RawQuerySet.

Comment: You can also try: kwargs["queryset"].all = kwargs["queryset"].__iter__