# Django: How to use django.forms.ModelChoiceField with a Raw SQL query?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to render a form with a combo that shows related entities. Therefore I'm using a ModelChoiceField.

This approach works well, until I needed to limit which entities to show. If I use a simple query expression it also works well, but things break if I use a raw SQL query.

So my code that works, sets the queryset to a filter expression.

```
class ReservationForm(forms.Form):
    location_time_slot = ModelChoiceField(queryset=LocationTimeSlot.objects.all(), empty_label="Select your prefered time")

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    city_id = kwargs.pop("city_id")     # client is the parameter passed from views.py
    super(ReservationForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    # TODO: move this to a manager        
    self.fields['location_time_slot'].queryset = LocationTimeSlot.objects.filter(city__id = city_id )
```

BUT, if I change that to a raw query I start having problems. Code that does not work:

```
class ReservationForm(forms.Form):
        location_time_slot = ModelChoiceField(queryset=LocationTimeSlot.objects.all(), empty_label="Select your prefered time")

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        city_id = kwargs.pop("city_id")     # client is the parameter passed from views.py
        super(ReservationForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        # TODO: move this to a manager        
        query = """SELECT ts.id, ts.datetime_to, ts.datetime_from, ts.available_reserves, l.name, l.'order' 
    FROM  reservations_locationtimeslot AS ts
     INNER JOIN reservations_location AS l ON l.id = ts.location_id 
     WHERE l.city_id = %s     
     AND ts.available_reserves > 0  
     AND ts.datetime_from > datetime() """

    time_slots = LocationTimeSlot.objects.raw(query, [city_id])

    self.fields['location_time_slot'].queryset = time_slots
```

The first error I get when trying to render the widget is: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'

I could solve that one thanks to one of the commets in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196673/how-to-restrict-dropdown-in-django-admin), by doing:

```
 time_slots.all = time_slots.__iter__ # Dummy fix to allow default form rendering with raw SQL
```

But now I'm getting something similar when posting the form: 
'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'get'

**Is there a proper way to prepare a RawQuerySet to be used by ModelChoiceField?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you actually need a raw query there?  Just looking at that query, I can't see any reason you can't just do it with `filter(location__city=city_id, available_reserves__gte=0, datetime_from__gt=datetime.datetime.now())`.

Raw query sets are missing a number of methods that are defined on conventional query sets, so just dropping them in place isn't likely to work without writing your own definitions for all those methods.

Comment: Yes, I posted an over-simplified query. The one in production is much more complex and expected to grow :-(
So in conclusion you say that Symfony's ModelChoiceField is not prepared to use RawQuerySets?

Comment: A `ModelChoiceField` is not set up to use a raw query set unless you fill in the necessary methods, no.  Depending on your situation it might be useful to declare a view in your database, then create an unmanaged model in Django to represent it.  You'd have to do extra work to convert the chosen view entry back to a real model instance, but that shouldn't be too hard since you can keep the PKs the same.

Answer (score 1):

I temporarily fixed the problem adding the missing methods. 
The way I'm currently using the ModelChoiceField I only needed to add the all() and get() methods, but in different scenarios you might need to add some other methods as well. Also this is not a perfect solution because:
  1) Defining the get method this way migth produce incorrect results. I think the get() method is used to validate that the selected option is within the options returned by all(). The way I temporarily implemented it only validates that the id exists in the table.
  2) I guess the get method is less performant specified this way.

If anyone can think of a better solution, please let me know.

So my temporary solution:

```
class LocationTimeSlotManager(models.Manager):
    def availableSlots(self, city_id):
        query = """SELECT ts.id, ts.datetime_to, ts.datetime_from, ts.available_reserves, l.name, l.'order' 
            FROM  reservations_locationtimeslot AS ts
            ..... 
            ..... 
            MORE SQL """ 

        time_slots = LocationTimeSlot.objects.raw(query, [city_id])

        # Dummy fix to allow default form rendering with raw SQL
        time_slots.all = time_slots.__iter__ 
        time_slots.get = LocationTimeSlot.objects.get

        return time_slots
```